# Order a table according to a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used a recursive CTE to obtain the table below.

```
CREATE TABLE PositionTree(
    OID int, 
    Position int, 
    Parent int, 
    Name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO PositionTree
(OID, Position, Parent, Name)
VALUES
(23, 21, 2,  'Supervisor'),
(34, 18, 18, 'Supervisor+3'),
(37, 1, 18, 'Supervisor+2'),
(89, 25, 21, 'Target Employee'),
(1129, 2, 1, 'Supervisor+1')
```

I would like to generate an index such that I can arrange the table to start with `'Target Employee'` and ascend up through `'Supervisor+3'`.  You may assume that I know in advance the OID of the target employee (this will eventually go into a stored procedure, with the target OID as a parameter)

The resulting table should look similar to this:

```
OID  Position  Parent  Name               SortOrder
89   25        21      'Target Employee'  0
23   21        2       'Supervisor'       1
1129  2        1       'Supervisor+1'     2
37    1        18      'Supervisor+2'     3
34   18        18      'Supervisor+3'     4
```

Ideally, I would just pull an index out of the recursion (start at 0, and one at each step of the recursion), but I haven't found anything pointing me to how to do that.  Is getting such an index from the recursion possible, or what is the best way to get this table sorted as I want it?

### EDIT:

The solution, as pointed out by HoneyBadger, is in adding a little bit the the CTE.  For example:

```
PositionTree AS
    (
        SELECT OID, Position Parent, Name, 0 AS SortOrder
        FROM SomeTable
        WHERE OID = @oid

        UNION ALL

        SELECT R.OID, R.Position R.Parent, R.Name, SortOrder + 1 AS SortOrder
        FROM SomeTable R
            JOIN PositionTree PT 
                ON PT.Parent = R.Position 
    )
```

Comment: will there only be up to 4 supervisors?

Comment: No.  There is no limit to the number of supervisors.  But we do know that the ascension stops when `Parent = Position` (a person is his or her own supervisor).

Comment: @HoneyBadger, please move it to an answer. Thanks

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Answer added

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Thanks, upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels a bit to short for an answer, but by request:

It would be easier to answer if you showed your recursive CTE, but you can just select `0 as SortOrder` in your anchor, and in your recursive part select `SortOrder + 1 as SortOrder`.

Comment: Wow.  That was so much easier than I was making it.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the working query for others with similar issues? Thanks.

Comment: Edited my post with the necessary query.